# Webpack 4.16.3 is not respecting setting the mode

Tags: webpack, angular6

Currently am working on .NET Core 2.0, Angular 6 and using VS2017 as my editor.

Webpack 4.16.3 is not respecting the mode setting in package.json file.

Here is my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack --mode development",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
"@angular/common": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "6.1.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.1.1",
"@types/chai": "4.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
"angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.0",
"bootstrap": "4.1.3",
"chai": "4.1.2",
"css": "2.2.3",
"css-loader": "1.0.0",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
"expose-loader": "0.7.5",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "1.1.11",
"html-loader": "0.5.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.7",
"karma": "2.0.5",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
"preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"rxjs": "6.2.2",
"style-loader": "0.21.0",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"typescript": "2.9.2",
"url-loader": "1.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.16.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.3",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.3",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
 },
 "dependencies": {
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
"ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
"npm": "^6.2.0",
"w3-css": "^4.1.0"
}
```

When i run the application the build is twice as slow as it was when webpack version was webpack ~V3. 
Here is the warning from the console:

***[HMR] bundle has 4 warnings
client.js:189 configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  main-client.js (1.2 MiB)
  0.0338b4a2c00f8368abd9.hot-update.js (810 KiB)
entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main-client (2 MiB)
      main-client.js
      0.0338b4a2c00f8368abd9.hot-update.js
webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/***

Please let me know how we can set the mode correctly in webpack ~4.

Comment: try forcing, adding to your config file

Comment: yeah when i force it in the config file, it works. But is that an ideal solution?

Comment: Yep. In this case, there is no "correct" solution. Both are acceptable. Personally, i prefer putting on the config file.